# Can we connect Earth , Neutral and Digital Ground together in electronics system?

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, embedded, emc, system

In our project has Digital Ground , Earth and Neutral.
As per the requirement Digital Ground and Earth ground tied through Bead inductor.

Is it advisable to connect Neutral with Chassis and Digital Ground ??

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3ZJT8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain why you think it would (ever) be a good idea to connect earth or your digital ground to mains neutral? Can you see any potential problems?

Answer (score 8):

No, do not connect neutral to earth or digital ground. In some parts of the world the mains plugs are not polarized so there is a 50% chance it ends up connecting live to earth or digital ground.

Answer (score 2):

It may depend where you are, but in the UK neutral and earth **must not** be connected together downstream of the supplier's intake.

Joining N-E would trip any Residual Current Device (USA: GFCI)

A surge protector circuit might be connected across L and E but this should not pass appreciable current under normal circumstances. The amount of residuial current permitted to be passed, and the effect of EMC filters on leakage, is discussed [here](http://www.marcspages.co.uk/pq/3333.htm) and the effect of common mode noise currents on RCDs [here](http://www.marcspages.co.uk/pq/3342.htm)

The reason why N-E would trip any RCD is that the current passing through L and N must be equal. If there is a fault (or link between N and E) the full current will through through the RCD L, but some will return through RCD N and some through E. Therefore L and N will not balance, and the RCD will trip. This diagram from [DIYnot](https://www.diynot.com/diy/threads/neutral-earth-rcd-trip.524675/) illustrates:

[image: RCD N-E fault]

Comment: "Joining N-E would trip..." Can you elaborate on that a bit? It is clear to me how that might happen, but I think it is worth clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

In a general way, the earth is connected to a metal plate buried near the point of usage (in your garden for example). It is used to protect yourself from electrocution by connecting all metal plates of your device to the earth, this way, during an electrical short-circuit the current will "prefer" return to the earth through the cable than going to the earth through you. For example, the metallic carcass of a washing machine is connected to the earth.

The Neutral is connected to a metal plate buried in the Earth at the Transmitting Station, it provides a reference to the line supply (your +5V pin on an arduino card for example, the neutral would be the GND pin in an Arduino card).

In a general way, **the Neutral and the Earth should be separate**. The earth wire is not supposed to carry current in normal condition, otherwise, it may have some charges across and it will become hazardous.

The digital ground provides a reference for the voltage of digital logic. 
**Now the same way you should separate Neutral and the Earth wires, you should separate digital ground and the Earth wires for the same reasons.**

The Neutral and the digital ground might be separated depending on your application. The main advantage is to isolated different applications. For example, the neutral could be used for analog purpose while the digital ground is reserved for digital purpose.